# Clearing model in Bootstrap-UI's typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using Bootstrap-UI's typeahead directive, and I want to clear the model on select, and thereby clear the typeahead field (values will be stored elsewhere).

I just can't seem to get the typeahead update, after I have cleared the model.

I have created a plnkr which displays the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/NitVqHyfE3pfSUIhjUZ3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used incorrect model name. The model you used is called `selected` not `selectedBrandInput`.

```
  $scope.onBrandSelect = function ($item, $model, $label) {
      $scope.state = $item;        //save it somewhere
      $scope.selected = undefined; //instead of $scope.selectedBrandInput = null;
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
          $scope.$apply();
      }
      console.log($item)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Best solution I could found is

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead('val', myVal);
```

using [this reference](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)

You can set empty string through this method  $('.typeahead').typeahead('val', "");

this will empty the list.